# Permalink sub-routing catch-all

Tags: permalinks, mod-rewrite

I have a client side web application which is loaded for two post types: `/tutorial` and `/dashboard`. WordPress routing works fine for the individual posts: `/tutorial/tutorial-1` and `/dashboard/dashboard-1`.

However, in my client side app, I want to handle additonal route fragments: `/tutorial/tutorial-1/quiz`. My React router handles the URL fine when loaded, but when directly linked WordPress is giving a 404 because although a permalink for `/tutorial/tutorial-1` exists, it can't match the last fragment.

I am assuming I need to do a rewrite rule, but it has been a long time since I wrote those for Apache. Basically I need to match `/[post-type]/*` to route to the post type.

As requested post type registration:

```
$args = array (
    'label' => esc_html__( 'Tutorials', 'tutorial' ),
    'labels' => array(
        'menu_name' => esc_html__( 'Tutorials', 'tutorial' ),
        'name_admin_bar' => esc_html__( 'Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
        'add_new' => esc_html__( 'Add new', 'tutorial' ),
        'add_new_item' => esc_html__( 'Add new Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
        'new_item' => esc_html__( 'New Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
        'edit_item' => esc_html__( 'Edit Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
        'view_item' => esc_html__( 'View Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
        'update_item' => esc_html__( 'Update Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
        'all_items' => esc_html__( 'All Tutorials', 'tutorial' ),
        'search_items' => esc_html__( 'Search Tutorials', 'tutorial' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => esc_html__( 'Parent Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
        'not_found' => esc_html__( 'No Tutorials found', 'tutorial' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => esc_html__( 'No Tutorials found in Trash', 'tutorial' ),
        'name' => esc_html__( 'Tutorials', 'tutorial' ),
        'singular_name' => esc_html__( 'Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => false,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite_no_front' => false,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'thumbnail',
        'excerpt',
        'comments',
        'revisions',
    ),
    'description' => 'A tutorial',
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-exerpt-view',
    'rewrite' => true,
    'show_in_graphql'     => true,
    'graphql_single_name' => 'tutorial',
    'graphql_plural_name' => 'tutorials',
);

register_post_type( 'tutorial', $args );
```

Comment: What's the code you use to register the post type `tutorial`?

Comment: @SallyCJ updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an internal rewrite so WordPress recognizes these requests. In the same function hooked to `init` where you add the post type, you can add:

```
add_rewrite_tag( '%tutorial_fragment%', '([^/]+)' );

add_rewrite_rule(
    'tutorial/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?tutorial=$matches[1]&tutorial_fragment=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

The value is available via the WP API after the request is parsed:

```
$value = get_query_var( 'tutorial_fragment' );
```

After any changes to rules, flush them [with code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/), or by visiting the Settings > Permalinks page.

Comment: I went with simply this `add_rewrite_rule( 'tutorial(\/.*)?$', 'index.php?post_type=tutorial', 'top' );` as I only need to know the post type - my React app takes care of the routing once loaded. Many thanks - I would have missed the flushing had you not told me.